# Continuous NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a NSTextField and Label whose value is bind to same NSString in the view Controller
[image]

The problem here is the label only gets updated when I press Tab.
How do I make it continuous, so that what ever I type in the text box gets reflected in the label immediately?
As of now I am using `-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj;` selector, but I am expecting a binding only solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the relevant `NSTextField` in Interface Builder, then navigate to the *Bindings Inspector*. You need to make sure *Continuously Updates Value* is checked:

[image]